# comparision of arraylist

Tags: java

hi am storing the results in array list which are obtained by querying  different database in java. i need to compare this array list to get the common rows

```
      List name = new  ArrayList();
      name.add(Spreadsheets.getString("Name"));

     List namedb = new  ArrayList();
     namedb .add(rs.getString("eName"))
```

in c++ we use strcmp to compare. but in java how do i compare this arraylist and it should return common rows. or how do i apply binary search algorithm to search these to arraylist?

Comment: I would suggest the namesDB.retainAll( names ) method shown below by Triztian, but note depending on the sizes of your arrays, the efficiency could be very poor.  If the names are unique, I'd use a Set<String> instead of ArrayList<String>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the List's [`retainAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method.

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> namesDB =  new ArrayList<String>();

// Get some names ??
names.add(Spreadsheets.getString("Name"));

boolean hasCommonNames =  namesDB.retainAll( names );

// The namesDB will only contain the common names.
if( hasCommonNames ) {
    // Do something with the common names
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashMap to store the first set of results , and then iterate through the second list , during iteration check if that value exists in the HashMap , if it exists , push it into another List C , at the end of the iteration , List C will have the common elements

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> a3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();               
for (String a : a1)
    a3.add(a2.contains(a) ? 1 : 0);
```

Now check content of a3. If all is 1, two list are same...